# React Router 4 Navbar props not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am building a small project to test the React Router 4. So far so good, my url updates and my props.locations shows up with withRouter. But I can't seem to change my navBar base on the props.location.

This is what my Routes look like:

```
<Provider store={ store }>
   <BrowserRouter onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
      <div className="root">
      <App/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
        <Route eact path="/signin" component={SignInContainer}/>
        <Route eact path="/reviews" component={Reviews}/>
        <Route path="/favorites" component={Favorites}/>
        <Route render={() => (
          <p>Page Not Found</p>
        )}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

My  component basically contains my HeaderBar and navBar, I have messages thats in navBar that I want to change so I would have title of the page, My App looks like this:

```
const App = (props) => {
  let toRender = null;
  if(props.location.pathname !== '/signin'){
    toRender = (
      <div>
        <HeaderContainer />
        <NavBarContainer />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    toRender = null;
  }

  return(
    <div className="App">
      { toRender }
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can import my navBar container into each of the routes i have for '/', '/reviews', and '/favorites'. But I don't think that would be a modular way to do it. I also have a shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method inside NavBar, and I tested with a console.log to print something when it does update when I switch url, but it doesn't. Does anyone have any suggestions on a clean solution to pass in the props to my NavBar without importing it into every single one of the components? I also tried putting App component in the place of Route so I would have:

```
<App exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer}/>
<Route eact path="/signin" component={SignInContainer}/>
<App eact path="/reviews" component={Reviews}/>
<App path="/favorites" component={Favorites}/>
```

But then my Components aren't rendering besides the App. I'm not sure what's happening or why it's not rendering the components. Any suggestions would be much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a quick refresher with the [switch docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md) would help

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks! That explains why I can't use App in children of Switch. I'm still not sure why my lifecycle methods in App are not being affected by prop change from the route change. I will experiment more with it.